# Universal Image Loader custom ImageDownloader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I've implemented a custom BaseImageDownloader, and it's method `InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri, Object extra)`.

Everything works ok.

The thing is, some times, the file I'm opening is corrupt (out of my hands, it might happen) and I can detect when it does happen. Right now I'm returning null, and it produces a *null pointer exception*

```
ERROR/ImageLoader(21847): null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.utils.IoUtils.copyStream(IoUtils.java:39)
```

It does not break anything, since it's not closing the app, and the "fail" image is properly shown, I just don't like it throwing an exception.

Is there a proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could edit the ImageLoader code where the error is caused, but there is really no purpose for that. What is happening is exactly what exceptions were made for; errors that are expected to occur occasionally, but at unpredictable times. That's why you handle it with a try/catch block...

Answer (score 0):

As it is out of your hands, the only thing you can do is retry, after some time perhaps.